# Packing of object and passing to driver in UVM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am very new to UVM. Kindly guide me ona good example on how to use driver for packing packet members and passing it to the driver DUT interface. Till now, I have been doing without pack, and sharing the code scrap of Driver (run phase)

```
    task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    begin
        Packet simple_seq;

        forever begin
            seq_item_port.get_next_item(simple_seq);
            drive_item(simple_seq);
            seq_item_port.item_done();
        end
    endtask

    task drive_item(input Packet pkt)
    begin
        @(dut_if.master_cb);
        dut_if.master_cb.Data_in_08p <= pkt.correct_data_in;
        dut_if.master_cb.Data_valid_08p <= pkt.valid_in;
    end
    endtask
```

Instead of doing the drive_item, I want to first pack the object and then call do_pack in driver to pass it to interface, but not sure how to do it. My do_pack function is

```
function void do_pack(uvm_packer packer);
  super.do_pack(packer); 
  packer.pack_field_int(correct_data_in,$bits(correct_data_in));
  packer.pack_field_int(valid_in,$bits(valid_in));
endfunction : do_pack
```

A good example on how the driver would use this do_pack function would suffice for me. This is just for practicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to instantiate a [uvm_packer](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/base/uvm_packer-svh.html) object (and probably also set its [endianness property](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/base/uvm_packer-svh.html#uvm_packer.big_endian)).  Once you do that, you should be able to pack your `Packet` class object into a bit array.  Then you can pass the resulting bit array into a task that you would have to add into your SystemVerilog interface.

```
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    uvm_packer packet_packer;
    bit bitstream[];
    int num_bits;

    packet_packer = new;
    packet_packer.big_endian = 0;
    begin
        Packet simple_seq;

        forever begin
            seq_item_port.get_next_item(simple_seq);
            num_bits = simple_seq.pack( bitstream, packet_packer );
            dut_if.drive( bitstream );
            //drive_item(simple_seq);
            seq_item_port.item_done();
        end
    endtask

    task drive_item(input Packet pkt)
    begin
        @(dut_if.master_cb);
        dut_if.master_cb.Data_in_08p <= pkt.correct_data_in;
        dut_if.master_cb.Data_valid_08p <= pkt.valid_in;
    end
endtask
```

In the code that I have shown above, `num_bits` is just a dummy variable used to store the number of bits that have been packed.  The `drive` task in the interface would look similar to this (assuming that `correct_data_in` is 4 bits wide and `valid_in` is a 1-bit signal):

```
task drive ( bit bitstream[] );
  @(master_cb);
  Data_in_08p <= { bitstream[3], bitstream[2], bitstream[1], bitstream[0] };
  Data_valid_08p <= bitstream[4];
endtask : drive
```

A great explanation on how the uvm "do" hooks work (including the `do_pack`) is provided here:

http://cluelogic.com/2013/01/uvm-tutorial-for-candy-lovers-do-hooks/

It's important to note that packing/unpacking have nothing to do with how you decide to drive the RTL signals in your testbench.  Packing is just a way to convert your `uvm_object` into a bit array.  That is different from the strategy that you might choose in order to drive signals.  You can either have a `drive_item` task in the driver, or you can call a task in the interface and drive signals from there (The latter approach has some benefits when porting testbenches to an emulation platform).

Comment: So whats the difference by 1)  not using UVM_NOPACK and driving signals directly to the interface and    2)  using UVM_NOPACK and a do_pack function?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of num_bits here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a more on the drive task as in what should be on the rhs after packing into bitstream[]  i.e                           @(dut_if.master_cb);
 dut_if.master_cb.Data_in_08p <=   ??

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji : I have edited my post to answer these other questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation

Comment: Also, if you can let me know when we use `uvm_pack_intN(data) and when we use packer.pack_field_int(data, $bits(data)).

Comment: I have not used `uvm_pack_intN`.  You might want to ask a new question for that.